# What's the difference between "run" and "update" in js fiddle?

Tags: jsfiddle

There are 2 buttons in js fiddle. Whenever I change the code, I have to click "run" not "update" to see the change.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Run will execute the code you currently have in your fiddle windows.

Update will create a new version - you'll notice the URL append a number if it hasn't already got one, and then each successive update will increase that number. Think of them as versions.

Comment: i can switch btw them? where can I access every new version after I hit update button?

Comment: you can change the URL - say its on .../w5tqbnw/6 you can change that 6 to a 5 to see the previous version...